# ReentrantLock - automatically timeout long waiting locs

Tags: java, concurrency

I would like to use ReentrantLock, but we have the following use case : key that is lock must expired after N seconds or before by "unlock" method. "tryLock" method is not useful for use, because only caller of this method will be timeout, not the source lock. 
   Any idea how to do this? Thank you.
Regards,
   Matic

Comment: So, the lock can only be held for `N` seconds? What happens if it hasn't been unlocked by that point -- the holder is interrupted?

Comment: Yes, like you said - only be held max N seconds. And the holder should be interrupted.

Comment: So which thread would interrupt the holder once they exceed the time limit? And what says the holder respects interrupts anyways? I'm not understanding the use case here.

Comment: And how does the holding thread react upon being interrupted? What if it's in the middle of some transaction (the whole point of using locks, generally) -- how is it rolled back?